Why can't I use AnyStr as a return type in Python 3.12 with Pyright?
Consider the following code:
def get_secret(self, name: str, **kwargs: Any) -> AnyStr:
   kwargs["SecretId"] = name
   result = self.client.get_secret_value(**kwargs)
   return result["SecretBinary"] if "SecretBinary" in result else result["SecretString"]

It yields the following error:
Expression of type "bytes" cannot be assigned to return type "AnyStr@get_secret"
  Type "bytes" cannot be assigned to type "AnyStr@get_secret"PylancereportReturnType

It works, if I specify the name parameter to be of type AnyStr and return it verbatim.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.AnyStr

The docs give the definition of AnyStr inline: AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', str, bytes), which indicates that it is a type variable. Type variables should appear 2+ times in a signature, so unless AnyStr implicitly parameterises the type of self, your signature is incorrect. name: AnyStr makes the type variable appear twice in the signature, hence the error disappears.

Thank you. You say: Type variables should appear 2+ times in a signature. Is that a general rule? I have never heard of that before. By "2+", you mean at least two times? Couldn't I define TypeVar('T', MyClass) and use it only once in a signature? Why not?

2+ means two or more times. Pyright will explicitly emit warnings which say TypeVar "T" appears only once in generic function signature (see e.g. pyright-play.net). The last example with U is due to the class binding.

Thank you again! But what's the reasoning for not allowing a single instance of a type variable in a function signature?

Well, I can't think of a situation where a type variable appearing once in a callable's signature would provide more info than annotation with a concrete type (with either the typevar's upper bound, or a union of its constraints). Do you have a counterexample?

No, I don't have an example, but I totally get your reasoning here: that it may be substituted be a concrete type. Thus, I think it should be a "warning" and not an "error" :)
